# JSTL using ${ } within ${ }

Tags: jstl, el

I'm wondering if the following is possible:

```
<c:forEach var="y" begin="0" end="${amountY }">
            <c:forEach var="x" begin="0" end="${amountX }">

                ${${x }-${y } }
            </c:forEach>
            <br />
        </c:forEach>
```

I have already set a certain amount of attributes with names being as follows:

```
"an x value" + "-" +"a y value"
```

The point of the foreach is to call on these attributes but I don't know beforehand how many there will be.

Now I'm wondering if there's a way to do this with maybe a different syntax cus it's not working this way.

Otherwise is it maybe possible to fill a list with strings and have each string be a certain piece of html code. Then foreaching that list so the strings get implemented as html? Probably not but w/e.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't nest el expressions like that.

First use `<c:set>` to create a new EL variable.

```
<c:set var="name" value="${x}-${y}" />
```

Then use it as key to access the attribute value in a specific scope, e.g. `${requestScope}`, or `${sessionScope}`, or `${applicationScope}`, depending on where you stored the actual values.

E.g. if it's in the request scope:

```
${requestScope[name]}
```

Needless to say that this is awkward design. Consider using a collection of maps or beans instead.